# Typo3 TCA mark thumb photo

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

```
    'main_photos' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:my_ext.main_photos',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'group',
            'internal_type' => 'file',
            'uploadfolder' => 'uploads/LLL:EXT:my_ext',
            'show_thumbs' => 1,
            'size' => 5,
            'allowed' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'],
            'disallowed' => '',
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 10,
        ),
    ),
```

I have multiple images loader. I want to mark one of this photos as main, such as in news.[image]
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as it's described in the docs.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Ctrl/Index.html#thumbnail

Add a key 'thumbnail' to your config and have it point to the column name that contains the images you would like to use as thumbnails.

```
'config'=>array(
    ...
    'thumbnail' => 'image',
    ...
)
```